# Groovy XMLSlurper appendNode - how force it to take effect?

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I understand that XML document changes are not immediate when using Groovy's XMLSlurper and StreamingMarkupBuilder.  However, I'm not happy having to do a lot of processing whenever I change a document.  The only way I've gotten it to work is if I do this:

```
    ...
labDoc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(serializeXml(labDoc))
...
def String serializeXml(GPathResult xml){
XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.declareNamespace("lab", "www.myco.com/LabDocument")
        mkp.yield labDoc
  } )
}
```

every time I append a new Node.  There has to be a better way!  Can anyone help?

Comment: So are you using `XmlSlurper` as the model for your application?  Why not use the slurper to get your initial data into some sort of more formal structure (list of elements, etc), manipulate this data, then write it out as XML when you are done?  Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: How would I do that? Still through Groovy?  Or JDOM or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLParser would be a better option as it allows for immediate feedback on the inserted nodes.

Comment: I hate to give up all the benefits that are available via the slurper... I can't believe that Groovy's XML modification support is this clunky!  But I've not been able to find a solution.